# alignComponent не работает для LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Почему когда в `RelativeLayout` выбираешь `alignComponent`, то никакой компонент не прикрепляется к `LinearLayout`, а к другим View-компонентам прикрепляются?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разметка:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#0079e8">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="elbase"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp" />

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fragment1Logo"
    android:src="@drawable/fragment1Logo" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="- это\n то, что совместит всю учебу в одном месте "
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Логин" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="Пароль" />
   </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/fragment1Login" />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Регистрация"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В атрибутах`LinearLayout` присвойте ему id - `android:id="@+id/layout"`, т.к. связывание виджетов в `RelativeLayout` происходит по их id:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:measureWithLargestChild="false">

 ...

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout"
    android:src="@drawable/fragment1Login" />
```

Это справедливо не только для `LinearLayout`, но и для всех прочих виджетов, которые необходимо связать в `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: ахаха, Вот это прикол. Теперь ясно. Не понятно только почему в Android Studio при создании linearLayout у него пустой id. Странно эт все конечн. 
Спасибо))

Comment: @xTIGRx Потому, что это контейнер для группировки виджетов, а не отдельный виджет. Контейнерам по умолчанию не назначаются id, т.к. они редко им нужны. Пока еще ни у кого не отвалились руки, чтобы прописать его самостоятельно при необходимости :) . Так же рекомендую вам давать более осмысленные имена своим айдишникам, а не те, которые присваивает студия по умолчанию. Иначе в проекте уже с пятком-десятком экранов у вас обязательно заболит голова вспоминать, какой такой textView12 и где он.